# How to learn debugging?

Tags: debugging

I am upper level CS major, and I have no idea how to do debugging. No where in my courses they are teaching/showing debugging, and all my course works goes like this  - here is the project, write a program in C that does XYZ, and by the way use GDB debugger.

Currently, I am taking Assembly language course, and instructor requires use of GDB debugger, hell I don't even know how to do debugging in Visual Studio. And all the projects we are going to do very soon, will require us to "hack" executable using GDB.

Any advice on how to get started/learn debugging, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have TAs available for questions?  I'm sure they'd be happy to help you out.

Comment: +1 for the TA's. They live for this sort of thing, they would be very happy to teach you because they'd be Duck Debugging their knowledge using you as their plastic duck. At least that's what I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no substitue for just doing it:

- Write a very simple program.
- Open it in a debugger.
- Run your program and step through
  each line.
- Use the debugger's commands to inspect
  your variables and program state.
- Write a more complicated program...
  Repeat...

If you have written projects on your course and not debugging at all, either you are writing loads of unit tests (that's a good thing), or your programs work first time.

The most important shortcuts for debugging in VS2010 (and 2008) are:

- Start Debugging         F5
- Start without Debugging Ctrl + F5
- Quit debugging          Shift + F5
- Step Into               F11
- Step Over               F10
- Step Out                Shift + F11
- Toggle Breakpoint       F9

Answer (score 1):

Practice makes perfect!

I would start writing some simple programs. Use whatever you're comfortable in. If you like Visual Studio, use Visual Studio. The concepts will be the same. Start setting breakpoints, looking at the watches, and see how values change throughout the run of the program.

Start making the programs more difficult and set goals for what you want to figure out with the debugger. You'll slowly become more proficient and figure out exactly how to step through your application, watch values, and examine the stack trace to figure out your bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that gaining at least a rudimentary knowledge of assembly, as well as knowledge about how your system implements function calls, as well as use of the registers, helps a great deal.  At the very least, being able to step through your program step by step and examine variables is a good start.  For more complicated matters, sometimes it helps to look at the disassembly.